# Looping in Render() function of ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects that I need to loop output on but am getting stuck. I tried using jQuery's .each() without success.

```
render: function() {
  return (
  $.each(events, function(k, e) {
     <div className="event-item-wrap">
     <div className="event-item" style="backgroundImage:e.Image">
       <div className="event-item-date">e.Date</div>
       <div className="event-item-title">e.Title</div>   
       <div className="event-item-price">e.Price</div>
       <div className="event-item-bottom">
         <div className="event-item-tags">
           <ul>
             <li>#professional</li>  
             <li>#livejazz</li>
             <li>#courtet</li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     </div>
     });
  );
}
```

My array contains simple Javascript objects with keys and values. How can I render them in React?

Comment: You are still in jQuery zone - ditch jQuery completely if you are making a react app, and use native for/foreach/map/for..of loops (or lodash/underscore), you probably would also not be dumping out markup like this and you are literally writing "e.Date" which is just text - please read the ReactJS documentation as there is a lot wrong with this

Answer (score 4):

Here is a example of how looping is usually done in **Reactjs**

```
var List = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
     return (
    { this.props.data.map(function(e) {
            var eventStyle = {
              backgroundImage:e.Image
            };

            return (
                     <div className="event-item-wrap">
                      <div className="event-item"style="{eventStyle}">
                      <div className="event-item-date">{e.Date}</div>
                     <div className="event-item-title">{e.Title}</div>   
                      <div className="event-item-price">{e.Price}</div>
                     <div className="event-item-bottom">
                      <div className="event-item-tags">
                  <ul>
                    <li>#professional</li>  
                    <li>#livejazz</li>
                    <li>#courtet</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>

            )
        })
    }
    );
 }
});



React.render(<List data={ (Array goes here) }  />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Dominic Tobias answer about, forgetting about jQuery, since we won't be manipulating the dom nor do we need to. For all other helpers use native functions or _. or give (es6 a shot) but in addition to the answer given by eugene safronov. I would like to recommend not to create the loop within the return itself, for readability and also for flexibility purposes. See example and the example below.

```
    var List = React.createClass({
        render: function () {
            var eventItems = this.props.data.map(function (item) {
            var itemStyle = {
              backgroundImage:item.Image
            };
                return (
                    <div className="event-item-wrap">
                        <div className="event-item"style="{itemStyle }">
                            <div className="event-item-date">{item.Date}</div>
                            <div className="event-item-title">{item.Title}</div>   
                            <div className="event-item-price">{item.Price}</div>
                            <div className="event-item-bottom">
                                <div className="event-item-tags">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>#professional</li>  
                                        <li>#livejazz</li>
                                        <li>#courtet</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            });

            return (
                <div className="app">
                    { eventItems }
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    React.render(<List data={ (itemsArray) }  />, document.body);
```

-- example with no data --

```
    var List = React.createClass({
        render: function () {

            var eventItems;

            if(_.isEmpty(this.props.data)) { // i used lodash/underscore _. for this example)
                eventItems = (
                    <span>No items to display</span>
                );
            } else {
                eventItems = this.props.data.map(function (item) {
                    var itemStyle = {
                      backgroundImage:item.Image
                    };
                    return (
                        <div className="event-item-wrap">
                            <div className="event-item"style="{itemStyle }">
                                <div className="event-item-date">{item.Date}</div>
                                <div className="event-item-title">{item.Title}</div>   
                                <div className="event-item-price">{item.Price}</div>
                                <div className="event-item-bottom">
                                    <div className="event-item-tags">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>#professional</li>  
                                            <li>#livejazz</li>
                                            <li>#courtet</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                });
            }

            return (
                <div className="app">
                    { eventItems }
                </div>
            );
        }
    });

    React.render(<List data={ (itemsArray) }  />, document.body);
```

it adds some extra flexibility, and readibility. I hope this helps u a bit, success with ReactJs!

(update: btw, now i used _. to check if data was empty, but u could also have checked if map returned nothing, and then show the different content, saves 1 extra function :D)